# Как написать этот команду на ms sql

Tags: sql-server

Я написал такую скрипт

"SELECT CATEGORY,USER_ID FROM TEST  GROUP BY CATEGORY,USER_ID ORDER BY USER_ID"

И результат так

CATEGORY | USER_ID

17 | 5

23 | 5

11 | 8

17 | 8

23 | 8

Мне нужен что ресултат было такая (Мне нужен count row на ms sql  ):

USER_ID | ROWS

5 | 2

8 | 3

Comment: `select user_id, count(distinct category) from test group by user_id`

Comment: Отформатируйте код